# Windows Switcher on Dual Monitor in Ubuntu 23.10 - Gnome 45

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-gnome

Is there a way to isolate window switcher on two monitor rather than installing this gnome extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/

because it doesn't work?